# UIBarButtonItem disappears when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a strange problem in my app. I have a `ViewController` which is inside a `UINavigationController`. I have added a `UIBarButtonItem` to `UINavigationItem` using storyboard. The button correctly shows when the application loads. However when I tap on the button, it disappears. I tried adding programmatically in `ViewDidLoad` and `ViewDidAppear` but the problem is still the same. The following is my code which I have written in `ViewDidLoad`

```
UIBarButtonItem *addFavoriteBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                                  target:self
                                                                                                  action:@selector(addToFavoritesBarButtonTapped:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addFavoriteBarButton];
```

Comment: when its disappers after button click or else

Comment: Add it in `viewDidLoad:` & check `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Test", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(actionToApplyBtnFromRefineView:)];`

Comment: It's not disappearing after click and what do mean by "I have a ViewController which is inside a UINavigationController" ?

Comment: It disappears after button click @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: can you show the code of button click

Comment: I mean that my ViewController is the RootViewController of UINavigationController. @JeckyModi

Comment: I am showing a UIActionsheet in the method which is called when I tap on the button. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @hamid there should be no issue, I just tried this thing. It's working perfectly. My button is not disappearing

Comment: show the code..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik
- (IBAction) addToFavoritesBarButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton = (UIBarButtonItem*)sender;
    
   UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"some title" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"button1", @"button2", nil];
    [actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:barButton animated:YES];
}

Comment: no no i m not asked this which one is not showing,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik i dont get your point bro

Comment: @hamid - which one is disappearing on your VC

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik the UIBarButtonItem which I have added to NavigationItem. It disappears after I tap on it. The code is already there in the question which I have asked

Comment: can you attach your project here , i wil check

Comment: Please check if there is any userDefined Attribute like selectedImage is there.